# Quantum computing coding setup for a beginner

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, textbook-and-exercises

I want to dive into Quantum computing but I don’t have a personal computer for coding. I have an iPad and I know some quantum computing basics. I had earlier used IBM quantum experience (IBM’s cloud quantum computing platform). I had used Qiskit and Jupiter notebook for coding and qubit simulations. So is there a way to use my limited resources (like my iPad and raspberry pi or beagle bone black or something else) to create a coding set up for myself?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is unlikely that an iPad, Raspberry Pi, or Beaglebone Black will have the power to run simulations and experiments for quantum computing. The intensive computational demands needed for quantum computing cannot be handled by these devices.

One choice would be to perform your simulations and experiments using cloud-based quantum computing platforms like IBM's Qiskit or Rigetti's Forest. There would be no need for additional hardware, only an internet connection and a platform account.

As an alternative, you may think about running your quantum computing simulations and experiments on a more potent machine or a cluster of computers. You would have more control and freedom, but it would take more time and money.

The ideal choice for you will ultimately depend on your unique requirements and available resources. I would advise doing some study and weighing your options to locate the one that best suits your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There are some development tools that allow you to write, execute, and even debug Python code in your browser and hence you can use them from iPad:

- [IBM Quantum Lab](https://lab.quantum-computing.ibm.com),
- [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com), and
- [qBraid Lab](https://lab.qbraid.com)

The experience will not be flawless though.

Comment: [qBraid Lab](https://lab.qbraid.com) is another good cloud-based option for Qiskit, but again, it won't be optimal from IPad.

Comment: Thank you. I added it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do "coding" per se, but I've creating circuits and run them on my iPad using [quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk)